# ZIP and copy backup from Windows server to Unix

Tags: windows, unix

I have a Windows application server which is working on weblogic. Everyday backup is happening for the server itself – it is increasing the load on the server. I have an HP Unix server for backup storage separately.

Now I need to zip the backup happening the D drive of Windows server to another drive (C or E) with the current date and from there I need to move to the backup server which is on HP Unix.

Thus, there will be 2 sources and 2 destinations:

- 1st source: the folder backup is happening
- 1st destination: moving to another drive as ZIP file
- 2nd source: the folder mentioned in 1st destination
- 2nd destination: the UNIX server I need to move to

I tried with `pscp` but it is failing when the size is large, so I need to try it with `robocopy` or `xcopy`.

Comment: I take back my close vote.

Comment: Is the problem the resulting zip is too large to copy? Can you use the option to save the zip in multiple parts (at least in 7zip) to solve the pscp problem?